# t-distribution difference between two datasets

Tags: statistics, probability-distributions, normal-distribution

> In a random sample of three pupils, $x_{i}$ is the mark of the *i*th pupil in a test on volcanoes and $y_{i}$ is the mark of the *i*th pupil in a test on glaciers. All three pupils sit both tests.
>
> It's believed that the difference between the results in the two tests follows a normal distribution with variance 16 marks. If the mean mark of the volcano test was 23 and the mean mark of the glacier test was 30, find a 95% confidence interval for the improvement in marks from the volcano test to the glacier test.

I got that:

$$(Y-X)^- \pm t \biggl(\frac{s_{n-1}}{\sqrt{n}}\biggr) = 
(30-23) \pm 4.303 \biggl(\frac{\sqrt{\frac{3}{2}(16)}}{\sqrt{3}}\biggr)=
7 \pm 12.171.$$

where *t* is the t-score associated with a 95% confidence interval for v=2.

Thus, I got the confidence interval [-5.171, 19.171]

But the answer key says the correct answer is [-11.1, 25.1].

Any ideas where I went wrong?

Answer (score 1):

Because you are told that the *population* variance of differences in scores is $\sigma^2 = 16,$ this should be a paired z-interval, not a t-interval.

You have $\bar D = \bar V - \bar G = 7,\, \sigma = 4,\, n = 3,$ so that the interval is
 $7 \pm 1.96(4/\sqrt{3}).$

If an answer key is wrong,
that would hardly be the first time ever, but it does warrant a second look.
First, please check that you
have posted the *exact* wording of the Question; second, please make sure
you have looked up the answer key correctly.  [Technically, if the *variance*
of the difference in test scores is $\sigma^2=16$ marks$^2$; then the *standard deviation*
would be $\sigma  = 4$ marks. I mention this inconsistency because $7 \pm 1.96(16/\sqrt{3})$
computes to $( -11.1057,  25.1057).$ Is it possible you typed 'variance' instead of 'standard deviation'?]